How to get System Voice and Rate from macOS System Settings to use with AVSpeechUtterance
I'm writing a SwiftUI app (multiplatform, but for now I'm just trying to get it working on macOS) which will be reading out a lot of text using AVSpeechSynthesizer. I will eventually add settings within the app to choose voices, speech rate, etc., but by default I thought I'd just have it use the default voice and speech rate set up as the System voice in the Spoken Content section of System Settings, which is used for a whole lot of built-in speech stuff. The problem is, it seems surprisingly difficult to do that!
On macOS it's this setting:

The rate and pitch can be set by tapping the ⓘ.
I think this used to be available on macOS under NSSpeechSynthesizer.defaultVoice, but this is deprecated now, and has never been available on iOS.
In my case I have the US English voice Victoria set up as my default voice, and if I explicitly ask for a US English voice with:
AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
I do actually get Victoria. But if I use:
AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.currentLanguageCode())
which would seem like the best idea on some unknown user's computer, I get the voice Karen, because my current language code is "en-AU" (The above screenshot shows that I have System speech language set to Use System Language. However, there is no way to explicitly set the System speech language to US English, as only the generic 'English' is available as an option.)
I suppose for many users, the second technique would work fine, but not all. In the generic case, how would I get the voice configured as the System voice?
And additionally, how would I get the rate and pitch settings to set for the rate and pitchMultiplier values on my AVSpeechUtterance? It doesn't seem like AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate changes according to this setting.
At this point I think I'll just add in settings for the voice etc. in my app from the get-go and hope that AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.currentLanguageCode()) and AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate are reasonable defaults, but I'm just really surprised that it seems so difficult to get or use the user's systemwide default settings. I don't want to force my users to configure something they've already configured in the system. Am I missing something?
